# R: package car not loading even though carData was installed

Tags: r, install.packages

I have been struggling to load the car package today, and given that I am rather new to R, I can't seem to make sense of the issue. The issue is that even after installing the package necessary (carData), there is still an error message asking me to install the the package when I try loading car.

I have installed the carData package using

> install.packages("carData")

I also tried

> install.packages("carData", dependencies=TRUE).

R responds by asking me to restart R before installing, I tried both restarting and not restarting to see if the trouble is due to that. The output after loading the package is the following:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/carData_3.0-5.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1821185 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/hv/v6hfqmxj4j57kq_rbw9zfnzw0000gn/T//Rtmp4vfcmV/downloaded_packages
```

So far so good, but then when I go for

> library(car)

I get:

```
Loading required package: carData
```

Does anyone have a clue what I could do to fix it? I am running R studio version 2023.03.0+386.

Comment: Everything's working as expected: you loaded the package, now you can use its functions/load its datasets. This should work after loading car  `adaptiveKernel(x = 1:2)` (this is a `car` function)

Comment: The terminology can be confusing. In R, you first *install* a package (aka library) to put the code on your computer, using `install.packages()`. Once that is done, you need to *load* that package in each session you want to use it, using `library()`. In this case, the `car` package relies on the `carData` package, so when you load `car` it loads the `carData` package too. The message is letting you know it did that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses, I have more confusing input from R now, suggesting that against all signs it doesn't work. In the top of my RStudio Script a little pop up is visible consistently saying: " Package car required but is not installed". It offers me to install it, but nothing seems to happen, as the header disappears only for a second to then reappear. 
In addition, once I command
>library(car)
a new error appears: Error in library(car) : there is no package called ‘car’